# Vertical inclination from pitch and roll

Tags: trigonometry, 3d, projective-geometry

I am a bit confused on how to compute the angle between R and the $z$-axis, knowing the roll($Ayz$) and the pitch($Axz$). We know also the length of R. Can someone help me please?

The schematic can be found here:
https://i1.wp.com/ozzmaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/logo2.png?resize=767%2C576

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found out:

We have to do a tangent on both roll and pitch, apply the Pythagorean theorem, and then arctan

```
inclination = atan(sqrt(tan^2(roll)+tan^2(pitch)))
```